# Site Self-Eval Question: Google's Search Results

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

Google has [this thing](http://www.computerweekly.com/news/1280091581/Google-tailors-search-results-based-on-user-behaviour) where it tailors the results of searches to the search history of that person or machine. If SE members who regularly search this site attempt Google searches, they are more likely to come up with stack exchange answers. As google searches are explicitly asked for while reviewing, should our searches take advantage of a any browser's ability to ignore history while performing our searches?

This means using "incognito" mode in chrome, or similar features of other web browsers. Should this be done the results of the site review are less unsullied by our own use of Stack Exchange? The scientist in me (which is a significant portion of me) *really* wants to use that incognito mode!

I want to see stack exchange beat out a lot of other places, since I really do think the SE method works well and is generally helpful, but I also want to the self-evaluation to be as honest as possible. Do we want the google-reflected self-bias, or is it inconsequential enough that we can ignore it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for helping with the site self-evaluation.

The best assessment of Google results will come from searches that aren't influenced by your own personal search history, so incognito mode is a big help here.  There are no *requirements*, and in practice the evaluation will reflect a mix of incognito searches, user-tailored searches, and no searches (not everybody is going to do exhaustive searches for every question, and I expect SE takes that into account).

So don't let an ideal of How Search Should Happen prevent you from doing the evaluation, but if it's easy for you to do incognito searches, that will tell us more about how likely our content will be found by people who don't already know about this site.